# Online Windows Server monitoring

Tags: monitoring

To check a website's availability there is Pingdom (and many others). I'm looking for a similar service (online/web-based, easy to use with notifications) that monitors servers a bit more in detail. Things like Disk Space, Windows Services running, etc....

I am happy to install an agent on the box to facilitate that, but don't want to run the monitoring server as well.

Answer (score 0):

On the inexpensive side we have used [ServersAlive](http://www.woodstone.nu/salive) for years.

Comment: Don't you need to install the server with this product as well? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me running a monitoring server as well.